# Rails hash iteration vs Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hashmap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been having some weird behavior. It's one of those issues that you look at and feel it shouldn't even be an issue!

Here is the skinny.

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {
    pending: 0,    # 0 account has a pending billing request (but is not yet open)
    active: 1,     # 1 account has an active base subscription
    suspended: 2,  # 2 account has been suspended (e.g. after a base subscription decline)
    expired: 3,    # 3 base subscription has expired
    incomplete: 4, # 4 partner application process incomplete
    closed: 5,     # 5 account has been permanently closed
    cancelled: 6   # 6 account has been cancelled by user (but is still unexpired)
  }
  after_initialize :setup_status_enums

  def setup_status_enums
    puts STATUS.inspect
    STATUS.each do |key, val|
      puts "Doing enum #{key}"
      define_method "#{key.to_s}?" do
        send("status") == key
      end

      define_method "#{key.to_s}!" do
         send("status=", val)
      end
    end
  end
end

{:pending=>0, :active=>1, :suspended=>2, :expired=>3, :incomplete=>4, :closed=>5, :cancelled=>6}
Doing enum pending

{:pending=>0, :active=>1, :suspended=>2, :expired=>3, :incomplete=>4, :closed=>5, :cancelled=>6}
Doing enum pending

{:pending=>0, :active=>1, :suspended=>2, :expired=>3, :incomplete=>4, :closed=>5, :cancelled=>6}
Doing enum pending

{:pending=>0, :active=>1, :suspended=>2, :expired=>3, :incomplete=>4, :closed=>5, :cancelled=>6}
Doing enum pending
```

(Over and over etc)

As you can see, it's only seeing "pending"

When I throw the inspected hash `{:pending=>0, :active=>1, :suspended=>2, :expired=>3, :incomplete=>4, :closed=>5, :cancelled=>6}` into IRB and run `each` etc., it works just fine. What in all that is holy am I missing?

Comment: is this a raw copy / paste of your code ? this seems crazy indeed

Comment: Rails vs. Ruby? Rails can't do anything vs. Ruby. Without Ruby Rails wouldn't boot or exist.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `map` when you should probably be using `each`?

Comment: Ah, yes sorry. I was using "each", and in my "thrashing" I tried map, because I was desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Just as I suspected. I don't feel totally bad, but it is still pretty stupid.

My rake tests were not bringing the failing code to the console, I'm not sure why, but when I run it in `rails c` I got undefined method exceptions. That's much more descriptive. I'm not sure why `rake test` was not showing me those errors.

At any rate, the fix is below.

```
        def setup_status_enums
        class << self
            STATUS.map do |key, val|
                raise "Collision in enum values method #{key}" if respond_to?("#{key.to_s}?") or respond_to?("#{key.to_s}!") or respond_to?("#{key.to_s}")

                define_method "#{key.to_s}?" do
                    send("status") == key
                end

                define_method "#{key.to_s}!" do
                    send("status=", val)
                end

                scope key.to_sym, lambda { where(status => val) }
            end
        end
    end
```

`define_method` needs to be in the `class << self` scope.

Thank you all for helping me dig into this. Maybe `rake` will show errors in the future...

Comment: this make sense. Also, you should have a look at [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), looks adapted to your problem - it will save you a lot of wiring.

Comment: @m_x, yea. I've looked into a lot of enumeration gems, none quite do them simply and cleanly enough. I'm taking one and gonna re-write a lot of it :)

Comment: not exactly an enumeration gem... a lot more. It helps you building a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Comment: Yea I've actually used that gem in another project, along with other ones too. More complicated than what I need for right now.